# How could I Async load a XPServerCollectionSource?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Is there a way to load XPServerCollectionSource in a Asynchronous way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DXperience 10.2 and later provides the [XPInstantFeedbackSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/clsDevExpressXpoXPInstantFeedbackSourcetopic) component for this purpose.